# How do I make a program where I can keep adding 1 to a value when a button is clicked?

Tags: java

I know this sounds very basic, but I never really learned how to do this.
I know about `for` loops where you can just use for example:

```
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

But that just prints out numbers from 0 to 10 with a gap of 1...which isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for some code where the program starts at a value and adds 1 (or another number) whenever the a button is clicked.

I already have the code for the button and everything, but I have an empty `ActionListener` as I don't know what to place inside it.

Comment: If you already have the action listener, just increment your number inside of it... it seems like you already know how.

Comment: it seems amazing to me for a moment that you know about `ActionListener` but not about incrementing a `variable` value

Comment: Show the code and make a guess how the increment can be added

Comment: @AnkitNigam Haha I know right xD.

Comment: Thanks for the edit whoever edited my question :).

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like this.

```
int counter = 0;       
JButton button = new JButton(" Click me ");
        //Add action listener to button
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                counter++;
            }
        });
```

This will make `counter++` execute whenever the button is pressed. If you want another number, say 10, then just replace `counter++` with `counter+=10`

****disclaimer****

Make sure that counter is accessible inside of ActionPerformed. You can do this by making it a field variable of an encapsulating class, making it a mutable object, and many other ways.

Comment: Consider making `counter` field of `ActionListener` since local/anonymous classes can access only fields, or effectively-final local variables. You can also use some mutable local variable where you wouldn't change its value, but state (like AtomicInteger, or simply `int[]{1}` array but that would be ugly).

Comment: Could you explain? If counter is a field variable then it can be accessed inside of actionPerformed i believe.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but from your answer it looks like `counter` is local variable which can't be incremented inside this `ActionListener` since it is anonymous class. I mean it would be better to either move it to this anonymous class, or make it some mutable object which state you could change (like `variable.setValue(newValue)` but not like `variable = newValue`).

Comment: I'm just assuming that all of this is being made inside a larger class, and that the actionlisteners are being added inside the larger class' constructor (thats how i'd do it) Thus, the variable (created as a field variable of the class) could be used inside the actionPerformed. Is this considered bad coding style?

Comment: If you want to make `counter` field of some larger class then that is also OK. My main point is to be explicit in your answer that `counter` is not local variable, but field since `counter++` won't work for local variables (they will no longer be effectively-final).

Comment: @Pshemo I'll edit and clarify, thank you, you've been a great help today.

Answer (score 1):

In the ActionListener actionPerformed method write the following code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getSource() == button_name)
      {
        count_variable += 1;
      }
}
```